# Initializing Template Array

Tags: c++, stl, vector, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to mimic the vector STL class. My constructor calls the following function which will allocate some memory for it on the heap. I want to initialize each of the objects, whether they be primitives or objects. I'm not sure of the syntax to achieve this. I just want the default constructor to be called. The line with `T(storage[i]);` shows the spot.

```
        void init_vector(uint reserve)
        {
            if (reserve == 0) reserve=1;
            _size = 0;

            storage = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*reserve);
            if (storage == NULL)
            {
                assert(false);
            }

            for (uint i=0; i<reserve; i++)
            {
                T(storage[i]); ???
            }
            _reserved = reserve;
        }
```

Comment: What you want is almost exactly how `std::vector` is implemented; the construction is performed by the allocator's `construct()` function (which in turn uses global placement-new).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

```
new (&storage[i]) T;
```

Comment: It should be `::new (&storage[i]) T();`, I suppose: We want value, not default initialization (think of non-class types); and we don't want to get derailed by overloaded placement-new operators.

Comment: Of course, if the memory is just reserved, why construct objects there at all?